# Does WPF provide default icon?

Tags: wpf, icons

Visual Studio or Google Chrome ( Windows 8 ) use the same icon ( Minimize, Maximize, Close window )
Is WPF provide these icon ? How Can i use it in WPF to make the Content of an Label control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use charmap to pick icon

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Name="Restore" Text="&#xE0A4;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="Minimize" Text="&#x2B12;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="Close" Text="&#x2581;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock> 
</StackPanel>
```

For more details visit this [Windows Store Apps: Change the icon of an AppBar Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799100/windows-store-apps-change-the-icon-of-an-appbar-button)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
 <Geometry x:Key="closeGeometry">
    F1 M 151,217L 152,217L 154.5,219.5L 157,217L 158,217L 158,218L 155.5,220.5L 158,223L 158,224L 157,224L 154.5,221.5L 152,224L 151,224L 151,223L 153.5,220.5L 151,218L 151,217 Z
</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="minimizeGeometry">
    M0,0 L8,0 8,1 8,2 0,2 0,1 z
</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="maximizeGeometry">
    F1 M 34,17L 43,17L 43,23L 34,23L 34,17 Z M 35,19L 35,22L 42,22L 42,19L 35,19 Z
</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="restoreGeometry">
    M1,4.9996096 L1,7.000219 7,6.999219 7,5.001 2,5.001 2,4.9996096 z M3,2.0014141 L3,3.0000001 8,3.0000001 8,4.0000001 8,4.0008045 9,4.0008045 9,2.0014141 z M2,0 L10,0 10,0.0010234118 10,1.0000001 10,5.001 8,5.001 8,7.9990235 0,8.0000239 0,4.0000001 0,3.0009998 0,3.0000001 2,3.0000001 2,1.0000001 2,0.0010234118 z
</Geometry>
```

I think your looking for this. if it is make use of it..

Comment: How could you know these value ?